# VB.net Get total time between two time spans

Tags: vb.net, timespan

I was wondering if there is a function with VB.NET that can tell me the total time that two different time spans have in common.

for example, I have these two different time spans:

```
1st Date : (2013-01-01 8:30 AM) - (2013-01-01 11:30PM)
2nd Date : (2013-01-01 10:00 PM) - (2013-01-02 6:00 AM)
```

Can VB.NET tell me that the answer is 1 hour and 30 mins? (perhaps in decimal)
It is 1 hour and 30 minutes because up to 10:00PM in the evening and 11:30 in the evening falls in with the other time span.

**Summary:**

I just need a function that will tell me how many hours in a certain timespan is a part of the night shift. (that's 10:00 PM to 6:00 AM).

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837675/timespan-intersection-in-c-sharp) what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you Neolisk, will look into it. Is there a VB equivalent to this though?

Comment: I tried translating his C# syntax into VB code, but I guess I'm doing a poor job at it.. is DATERANGE the same as DATERANGEVENTARGS?

Comment: @Malky.Kid Can 1st Date or 2nd Date span over two days or just a single day?

Comment: Okay date2 does span over two days.

Comment: @thunderbird 1st date span can cover 2 days. 2nd date span is actually fixed to : (DateToday 10:00:00PM) - (DateNextDay 6:00:00AM)

Comment: @Malky.Kid check out my answer i think it will work for your case without any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date1 and Date2 represents the first time span and Date2 and Date3 represent the second time span. If the order of the dates are changed you will have to define an analogous else to the first if.

```
    Dim date1 As Date = #1/1/2013 8:30:00 AM#
    Dim date2 As Date = #1/1/2013 11:30:00 PM#
    Dim date3 As Date = #1/1/2013 10:00:00 PM#
    Dim date4 As Date = #1/2/2013 6:00:00 AM#
    Dim timePeriod As TimeSpan

    If date3.Date >= date1.Date And date3.Date <= date2.Date Then
        If date4.Date <= date2.Date Then
            timePeriod = date4.TimeOfDay - date3.TimeOfDay
        Else
            timePeriod = date2.TimeOfDay - date3.TimeOfDay
        End If
    End If
    Msgbox(timePeriod.ToString)
```

EDIt: Just `timePeriod = date4- date3` will convert the difference into timespan

EDIT 2:The code above would have returned date2-date3 even if there there was no common time span. The code below would return 0 in such a case. Also when comparing two `Date` variables in an `If` statement, the `TimeOfDay` part is neglected.

```
        Dim date1 As Date = #1/1/2013 8:30:00 AM#
        Dim date2 As Date = #1/1/2013 11:30:00 PM#
        Dim date3 As Date = #1/1/2013 10:00:00 PM#
        Dim date4 As Date = #1/2/2013 6:00:00 AM#
        Dim timePeriod As TimeSpan
        If date3 >= date1 And date3 <= date2 Then
            If date4 <= date2 Then
                timePeriod = date4 - date3                  
            ElseIf date3 < date2 Then                   
                timePeriod = date2 - date3
            ElseIf date3.Date = date2.Date Then                    
                If date3.TimeOfDay < date2.TimeOfDay Then                        
                    timePeriod = date2 - date3
                Else
                timePeriod = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
                End If
            Else
                timePeriod = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
            End If
        End If
        MsgBox(timePeriod.ToString)
```

Comment: Sir, you deserve a cold beer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Malky.Kid Hey, i fixed an error in the code. Please see edit 2.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is available to all .Net languages via the `TimeSpan` class:

eg.:

```
result = (dt2 - dt1).TotalHours
```

When you subtract two dates you get a TimeSpan.
The TotalHours property of the TimeSpan gives you the number of hours, or part thereof.

Check out the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/269ew577(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DouglasBarbin: Intersection of intervals is a more complicated problem than that. You need to account for cases, 1) when your time intervals do not intersect (A before B, B before A), 2) have an interval in common, or one contains the other. You may end up using `TotalHours`, but it's not the solution by itself.

Comment: Right.  I should have phrased it better.  This would replace the DateRange class, but you would still need the other functions.

Comment: Ah, I must have misread the question, or it's been edited.  Anyways, my answer is incorrect, so please ignore.  Thanks for the vote of confidence Douglas! =)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  I think this is what you are looking for.

Here is your DateRange class:

```
Public Class DateRange
   Public Property StartTime As DateTime
   Public Property EndTime As DateTime
   Public ReadOnly Property NumberOfHours As Decimal
       Get
           Dim result As Double
           result += (EndTime - StartTime).Hours
           result += (EndTime - StartTime).Minutes / 60
           result += (EndTime - StartTime).Seconds / 3600
           Return result
       End Get
   End Property
End Class
```

This would be the C# function from the link, rewritten in VB:

```
Private Function GetIntersectionRange(range1 As DateRange, range2 As DateRange) As DateRange
    Dim iRange As New DateRange()
    iRange.StartTime = If(range1.StartTime < range2.StartTime, range2.StartTime, range1.StartTime)
    iRange.EndTime = If(range1.EndTime < range2.EndTime, range1.EndTime, range2.EndTime)

    If iRange.StartTime > iRange.EndTime Then iRange = Nothing
    Return iRange
End Function
```

Here is a little snippet of code to do the calculation you asked and write the answer to the console:

```
Dim firstDate As New DateRange With {.StartTime = New DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 8, 30, 0), .EndTime = New DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 23, 30, 0)}
Dim secondDate As New DateRange With {.StartTime = New DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 22, 0, 0), .EndTime = New DateTime(2013, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0)}

Dim result As DateRange = GetIntersectionRange(firstDate, secondDate)
Console.WriteLine(result.NumberOfHours)
```

Comment: Sorry.  I misunderstood.  Check my answer now.

Comment: I see, so we create a class for it. Thank you very much Douglas. I'll see what I can do with this

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
            Dim d1 As DateTime = "1/22/2018 8:30:00 AM"
            Dim d2 As DateTime = "1/29/2018 5:30:00 PM"
            Dim ts As TimeSpan = d2.Subtract(d1)
            MessageBox.Show("Total Hours are " & Convert.ToDouble(Math.Round(ts.TotalHours, 2)))
```

Just play around with it